# Filter options that were already selected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with an ng-repeat that loads a set of scheduled days a user has added.  Lets say the user has added the first day to the collection and selected Monday from the dropdown.  When the user adds a second day to the collection I would like the dropdown to filter out Monday because its already used, however not filter out Monday for the day that Monday was selected for.  Does anyone have an example on how to accomplish this?

Edit:

```
$scope.schedule = {days: []};
```

Updated from Zacks example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XV69S/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** Updated with the edit to the question ***

Here every time a choice is selected, it calls updateAvailability()

```
<div ng-repeat="schedDay in schedule.days">
    <select ng-model="schedDay.day" ng-change="updateAvailability()">
        <option ng-repeat="day in days|orderBy:value" ng-disabled="!day.selectable" value="{{day.day}}">{{day.display}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Which goes through and checks if it is already used elsewhere.

```
$scope.updateAvailability = function() {
    var used = $scope.schedule.days.map(function(day) {
        return parseInt(day.day || '-1');
    });

    angular.forEach($scope.days, function(day) {
        day.selectable = used.indexOf(day.day) === -1 ? true : false;
    });
}
```

Check out the demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/XV69S/)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the jsfiddle to better match what I have now.  Hopefully that will make better sense of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GaryLCoxJr Updated my answer to go with your changes.